# Spring Beans not detected in multi module project

Tags: spring, kotlin, dependency-injection, spring-integration

I have a multi module Gradle project following the clean architecture. I want to separate the Spring configuration which includes the scheduling tasks, configuring the use cases, etc, from the application entrypoints, like web controllers or like in this problem, Spring Integration components.

My project structure is the following:

[image: project structure]

This is the main Class with the necessary annotations for Integration

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableIntegration
class Main
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Main>(*args)
}
```

Under the entrypoints module I have a configuration file to configure spring integration with an adapter that process the messages

```kotlin
@Configuration
class InboundConfiguration(
    private val interceptorFactory: interceptorFactory,
    private val packageTransformer: PackageTransformer,
    private val packageHandler: PackageHandler,
) {

    @Bean
    fun tcpFlow(): IntegrationFlow {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(inboundAdapter())
            .transform(packageTransformer)
            .channel("persist")
            .handle(packageHandler)
            .channel("response")
            .handle(outboundAdapter())
            .get()
    }

    /* more beans declared e.g. inboundAdapter() method */
}
```

My issue is that the components that are constructor injected by the InboundConfiguration can't be found with the IDE message

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'interceptorFactory' type found

All the classes under the interceptor and components packages are spring components annotated with @Component, and some of them autowire bean dependencies declared in the configuration package e.g.

```kotlin
@Component
class PackageHandler(
    private val useCase: GetData
) : GenericHandler<DataPackage> {

    override fun handle(payload: DataPackage, headers: MessageHeaders): Any {
        /* implementation */
    }
}
```

In this example the useCase: GetData is the interface that refers to the use case implemented under the domain package, the bean that register it is declared in the configuration package.

I have tried to add the @ComponentScan annotation in the InboundConfiguraionClass, but that causes that the "external bean dependencies" to break like

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'GetData' type found.

Any suggestions to register the configurations necessary for the spring integration part, but also this module be able to use the beans declared in the configuration module?

Comment: Have you actually tried running the application, instead of trying to fix the IDE message. Sometimes the IDE doesn't have the full picture of all beans in the context and it is the easiest to just ignore the message.

Comment: I second that. Sounds more like an IDE issue which is really like that because there is an auto-configuration which does its stuff at runtime.